# How to get geolocation of facebook status using facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, geolocation

So I'm trying to get latitude and longitude of facebook statuses to map them, can someone give me some idea on how to do that.

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firs make the API call - `/me/statuses` to get all the status of the user. 

Permission required: `user_status`

[Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fstatuses%3Ffields%3Dplace)

You'll get the response as-

```
{
   "data":[
     {
       "id": "10152044171758611", 
       "updated_time": "2014-02-15T12:12:59+0000"
     }, 
     {
        "place": {
            "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
            "name": "XXXXXXX", 
            "location": {
               "city": "XXXXXXX", 
               "country": "XXXXXX", 
               "latitude": 28.573024614741, 
               "longitude": 77.230443565217, 
               "street": "XXXXXXXXXX", 
               "zip": "XXXXXXXX"
             }
        }, 
        "id": "XXXXXXXXX", 
        "updated_time": "2014-02-10T18:13:36+0000"
     }, 
     ... 
  ]
}
```

Check if the element has `place` field, that means this status has some place with it. Fetch the place details. That's it!

Comment: I'm still stuck here, FB multyquery is a bit confusing. But your answer helped a lot :D